# How does this Java while loop compare to python's while loop?

Tags: java, python

I'm taking a course on Java basics and we're asked to prompt the user for a noun. And we're using conditional statements to filter out "bad" language. If the user enters "jerk" or "dork", then the program starts back again to where it prompts the user for a noun. Although I can't say I understand how this while loop is even functioning. The order and syntax seems strange to me. [Java code for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUkui.png)

My first language is python. So how I would approach this problem is just something like this[Python code for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbezN.png)

First, I'm assuming "do" and "while" are always paired together to make a while loop in java? But why is "do" set before while? Seems odd. And in my python example, once a user enters a word that is valid, it sets the value ValidWord to False, hence exiting the loop. Where in the Java loop is this being done? Sorry if this a noob question but the videos in the course didn't really go over how this loop is working.

Comment: "First, I'm assuming "do" and "while" are always paired together to make a while loop in java?" absolutely not. Indeed, a `do-while` loop is a construct that is missing from Python. Every once in a blue moon I wish I could have it. Essentially, a `do-while` loop executes the body of the loop *at least once*, then checks the loop condition. A regular while-loop first checks the condition, then the body is executed, so potentially the body is never executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does **do while** means is that whatever happens do block will always run. then it is going to check if the condition in while block is true or not. If the condition in while block is true then it will again run the do block. In this kind of loop:

```
do{
//Some code
} while(condition);
```

things in do block runs atleast 1 time regardless if the condition is true or false.

Meanwhile we have simple while statement also:

```
boolean isTrueOrNot = true;
while(isTrueOrNot)
{
//Some code
}
```

Here we are putting condition in the while statement checking if it is true or not then only the block of code inside the while loop will work.

Comment: Thanks for the response and example code. I had no clue that do-while and while were two different types of loops in Java (really wish the course would introduce the different types of loops in java before asking the students to implement loops in their own code.)

Answer (score 0):

`do{} while(condition)` loop would always run the code block in {} first, then check `condition` is true or not.

`while (condition) {}` would check `condition` first, if it's false, the code block in {} would not be run at all.